# problems while reading a .csv file

Tags: r, read.csv

I'm using a tool called Meltwater to download tweets and news that contain certain keywords. The file seems to be a .csv, but when I try reading it with the following code:

```
test <- read.csv("C:/Users/Usuario/Downloads/esto_es_una_prueba - Nov 24, 2022 - 11 40 37 AM.csv")
```

it returns this error:

```
Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) : 
  invalid multibyte string at '<ff><fe>D'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 2 appears to contain embedded nulls
3: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 3 appears to contain embedded nulls
4: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 4 appears to contain embedded nulls
5: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 5 appears to contain embedded nulls
```

If I open the file with Excel, instead of getting one comma separated column, such as:

```
Date,Headline,URL
24-Nov-2022 11:38AM,prueba,https://twitter.com/Jessipaola24/statuses/1595788900215230467
```

I get a regular Excel file, like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9aGH.png)

I tried with different `seq =` , I tried reading the file as a .xslx with different libraries. Nothing seems to work. I only manage to open the file in R if I first open it on Xlsx and save it as a .csv/.xlsx file. But since I have to read many files, I'd like to lose this step.

Comment: You may specify the `fileEncoding` in `read.csv`

Comment: My goodness, i've been trying things since may. What fixed it was this combination: 
`sep = "\t", fileEncoding = "UCS-2LE"`